# PHP MySQL How to make mysql sum column if value of other column equals to apple

Tags: mysql

So i am trying to make inventory system, but I have come to a a problem that I cannot solve.

I basically have column `inventory` where I have numbers (like 10, 5, 8 etc) and in other column I have `item` (like apple, pea, orange)

I want it to sum `inventory` column of rows that have Apple as `item` column.

PS: i want to run it as query using mysqli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(inventory) FROM Table WHERE item = 'Apple';
```

Comment: Wow that was fast - I will try it.

Comment: It works, however I still need help. I am quite new to this stuff, how do I then echo the output? I got: $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(inventory) FROM Table WHERE item = 'Apple';"); and while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
// WHAT DO I PUT HERE // ?
}

Comment: just do echo $row[0];

Comment: That works tysm.

Comment: @RADEK Please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To get sum of inventory of each itmes you have try this :

```
SELECT SUM(inventory),item FROM Table group by item
```

For single item you can use :

```
SELECT SUM(inventory) FROM Table WHERE item = 'Itemname';
```